# Backfill uuid column in postgres, rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have added a new uuid column in an existing table. As recommended by [strong migrations](https://github.com/ankane/strong_migrations) gem, I want to backfill column value separately.

I have written following migration to add uuid column, which works fine:

```
  def change
    enable_extension 'pgcrypto' unless extension_enabled?('pgcrypto')
    add_column :table_name, :column_name, :uuid
    change_column_default :table_name, :column_name, 'gen_random_uuid()'
  end
```

I have got following migration to backfill data, but it does **not** work, as expected:

```
  def up
    Model.unscoped.in_batches do |relation|
      relation.update_all column_name: 'gen_random_uuid()'
      sleep(0.01) # throttle
    end
  end
```

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work"? Are you seeing an error?

Comment: No, the sql statement issued by rails sets column value to null. But I want to add random uuid to be assigned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the raw sql query solves the problem:

```
  def up
    Model.unscoped.in_batches do |relation|
      relation.update_all "column_name = gen_random_uuid()"
      sleep(0.01) # throttle
    end
  end
```